# How to make a bootable mac usb IN ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, mac, macosx

I screwed with some bin files in MAC OSX, and can't log in. Anyways, I want a bootable ubuntu usb so I can recover my files/look at the disks. I KNOW HOW TO MAKE A USB BOOTABLE IN MAC. However, I do not know how to make one in Ubuntu. I have a computer with ubuntu, but need to make a bootable usb FOR A MAC. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The firmware in newer Macs allows to boot standard UEFI bootable media, which are rather [trivial to create](http://askubuntu.com/q/395879/40581) and don't require special Ubuntu images.

Comment: The standard USB-image will boot on a mac if prepared according to instructions.

Answer (score 4):

You will of course need a OS X Installer Image. To get this you can follow the instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201372)

After you have got your installer media, you can use ubunut's built-in utility `Startup Disk Creator` to make a bootable USB. SO, open dash and search for  `Startup Disk Creator` and open it. Follow the on-screen instructions or refer to [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) document from ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing unetbootin

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

and using your mac iso, install it to your usb

Answer (score 1):

Don't even think about using Ubuntu to fix OS X.  Use the recovery partition which should be part of any modern installation of OS X, by booting and pressing CMD-R.  You can then repair as needed - perhaps even install a fresh OS X on top of your existing installation which can fix most broken things.

See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 for details.

If everything goes completely wrong, restore from a Time Machine backup.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to make a High Sierra 10.13.6 bootable USB drive, and the process turned out a bit more involved that just `dd`-ing the `dmg2img`-generated ISO to a thumb drive. So, leaving it here in case somebody else will need to.

This sequence is based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743075/how-to-make-a-bootable-osx-el-capitan-usb). Unlike El Capitan, High Sierra only needs BaseSystem.dmg, which also has enough free space to boot - so, the process overall can be simplified a bit.

1. Get an OS X .dmg file. This question on [apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) has all the links, but they are only accessible from OS X (if you had access to a live OS X at this point - you probably would've just used `createinstallmedia` already, right?). So, you'll need to find an alternative source.
2. Convert `.dmg` file to ISO (`dmg2img -v -i <imagename>.dmg -o <isoname>.iso`).
3. Mount .iso image. You can do it from GUI (right click, "Open with disk image mounter") or something like `mount -o loop <isoname>.iso <iso_mount_point>`
4. Find `BaseSystem.dmg` in the mounted image. Convert it to `.iso` as well (`dmg2iso -i BaseSystem.dmg -o BaseSystem.iso`)
5. Copy it to a thumb drive: `dd if=BaseSystem.iso of=/dev/sdX BS=1M`. In my case (High Sierra 10.13.6), 4Gb stick was sufficient, even though `createinstallmedia` requires 8Gb. It probably misses some utilities.
6. Mount the thumb drive (you might need to `apt-get install hfsprogs` to mount an HFS filesystem). From the first iso, obtained on step 3, copy `BaseSystem.chunklist` and `BaseSystem.dmg` on the thumb drive (actually, the latter might not be necessary - but it worked for me at this step and I stopped experimenting). `sync`, just in case.

This is it, you have a bootable OS X usb drive.