# How to make a bootable OSX El Capitan USB?

Tags: partitioning, usb, macosx

*I wasn't sure about posting this thread here, or on the apple community. However, as I am using a PC running Ubuntu, I am posting this here.*

My macbook pro (mid-2015) is out of service. I need to reinstall OS X on it. Note that I can't access the recovery partition; it has been wiped out too.

I have the `InstallESD.dmg` file, that I found online; I checked the hash value.

I would like to know **how to make a bootable USB device with that file.** Note that I have a USB key with a MBR partition. I am not sure, but it should be using GUID to be recognized by my macbook pro?

What I tried:

1. Convert the `.dmg` file to a `.iso` file, using `dmg2img`:

   ```
   $ dmg2img -v -i Downloads/InstallESD.dmg -o Downloads/ElCapitan.iso
   ```
2. Copy the `ElCapitan.iso` file on my USB key:

   ```
   $ dd if=Downloads/ElCapitan.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=16M && sync
   ```
3. Plug the USB key and boot.

Result: nothing happens, the USB key doesn't appear.

Comment: Just to make sure: are you holding **⌥** or **C** during boot?

Comment: I am holding the `ALT` button to access the startup disk menu, with the list of WiFi networks. The USB does not appear.

Comment: Copying `.iso` files to USB flash drives works for Ubuntu installation disks because these disks use a Frankenstein's Monster of a disk format. I don't know offhand if Apple's disks use anything similar. If not, the resulting disk won't be bootable, except *maybe* if you used [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and its ISO-9660 driver to kick off the boot process. You might have better luck with [Unetbootin,](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) [Rufus,](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) or something similar, but I've not checked that these tools support OS X.

Answer (score 10):

There's a ready [script](https://github.com/eprigorodov/mkosxinstallusb) that automates this whole process. Manually it's as mentioned in [MacWorld](https://www.macworld.com/article/2367748/os-x/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-10-yosemite-install-drive.html), but using the Linux tools:

---

`InstallESD.dmg` is an image of a GPT disk with HFS+ partition which contains installer files, but is not bootable itself.

Working as a `root`, convert `InstallESD.dmg` into raw image format and mount it using `kpartx`:

```
dmg2img InstallESD.dmg InstallESD.img
kpartx -a InstallESD.img
mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt/installesd
```

`InstallESD.dmg` contains another disk image, `BaseSystem.dmg`, which is a bootable installer disk. But writing it directly to the USB drive does not work, because that would create a partition with almost no free space and still lacking some important files.

Extract base system image `BaseSystem.dmg`, convert into raw and mount too:

```
dmg2img /mnt/installesd/BaseSystem.dmg BaseSystem.img
kpartx -a BaseSystem.img
mount /dev/mapper/loop1p1 /mnt/basesystem
```

Format the USB flash drive as HFS+:

```
sgdisk -o /dev/sdb
sgdisk -n 1:0:0 -t 1:AF00 -c 1:"disk image" -A 1:set:2 /dev/sdb
mkfs.hfsplus -v "OS X Base System" /dev/sdb1
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usbstick
```

Copy missing installer files (beware of ending `/`):

```
rsync -aAEHW --info=progress2 /mnt/basesystem/ /mnt/usbstick/
rm -f /mnt/usbstick/System/Installation/Packages
rsync -aAEHW -P /mnt/installesd/Packages /mnt/usbstick/System/Installation/
rsync -aAEHW -P /mnt/installesd/BaseSystem.dmg /mnt/usbstick/
rsync -aAEHW -P /mnt/installesd/BaseSystem.chunklist /mnt/usbstick/
sync
```

It is possible to copy with other tools (tar, cpio), just supply parameters preserving the most of file metadata. `rsync` supports also `-X` parameter, supposed to copy HFS+ extended attributes, but in practice it fails with the error "Operation not supported".

Answer (score 4):

If you can't start up from OS X Recovery (Option-R), try holding down (Option-Command-R) to start up from OS X Internet Recovery.

Your mac(mid-2015) should initiate recovery over the Internet.

Read more at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Answer (score 3):

This works! I used it for making  a usb from El Capitan installer, using the InstallESD.dmg that you find inside the InsallMacOSX.dmg.
There is no need to try using the script, as it works with the list of commands on the read me file. so This:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/OSX_InstallESD /mnt/OSX_BaseSystem /mnt/usbstick

# convert installer disk image to raw format
dmg2img "Install OS X .app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg" InstallESD.img
kpartx -a InstallESD.img
mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt/OSX_InstallESD

# convert base system disk image to raw format
dmg2img /mnt/OSX_InstallESD/BaseSystem.dmg BaseSystem.img
kpartx -a BaseSystem.img
mount /dev/mapper/loop1p1 /mnt/OSX_BaseSystem

# partition the USB flash drive, /dev/sdX
sgdisk -o /dev/sdX
sgdisk -n 1:0:0 -t 1:AF00 -c 1:"disk image" -A 1:set:2 /dev/sdX
mkfs.hfsplus -v "OS X Base System" /dev/sdX1
mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt/usbstick

# copy installer files
rsync -aAEHW /mnt/OSX_BaseSystem/ /mnt/usbstick/
rm -f /mnt/usbstick/System/Installation/Packages
rsync -aAEHW /mnt/OSX_InstallESD/Packages /mnt/usbstick/System/Installation/
rsync -aAEHW /mnt/OSX_InstallESD/BaseSystem.chunklist /mnt/usbstick/
rsync -aAEHW /mnt/OSX_InstallESD/BaseSystem.dmg /mnt/usbstick/
sync
```

Only things that need to take into account are:
Run all the commands it as root! so use "sudo su"
kpartx you need to add -v (verbose) to see which loop is created so :kpartx -av InstallESD.img
on my machines there was already 12 loops
every now and then use "df" just to see which partitions and names you have in your system. The only need you need to change on the lines are.
The "loop0p2" and the loop1p1 and the dev/sdX according to your usb mount.

At some point you need to umount the usbdrive if "mount point busy" message.

under i just paste my terminal history that gave me a working usb drive.
thanks all of the above for pointing into the right direction!
starts with "sudo su"
i already extracted from the installer the file InstallESD and is sitting in the working directory

```
38  dmg2img InstallESD.dmg InstallESD.img
   39  kpartx -av InstallESD.img
   40  mount /dev/mapper/loop14p2 /mnt/OSX_InstallESD
   41  dmg2img /mnt/OSX_InstallESD/BaseSystem.dmg BaseSystem.img
   42  kpartx -av BaseSystem.img
   43  mount /dev/mapper/loop15p1 /mnt/OSX_BaseSystem
   44  df
   45  history
   46  sgdisk -o /dev/sdb
   47  sgdisk -og /dev/sdb
   48  man partprobe  #got a message that the partition was not going to be visible untill I use partprobe or reboot
   49  partprobe -s
   50  sgdisk -n 1:0:0 -t 1:AF00 -c 1:"disk image" -A 1:set:2 /dev/sdb
   51  partprobe -s
   52  man kpartx
   53  kpartx -u
   54  kpartx -ul
   55  mkfs.hfsplus -v "OS X Base System" /dev/sdb1
   56  mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usbstick
   57  df
   58  umount /dev/sdb
   59  mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usbstick
   60  rsync -aAEHW /mnt/OSX_BaseSystem/ /mnt/usbstick/
   61  rm -f /mnt/usbstick/System/Installation/Packages
   62  rsync -aAEHW /mnt/OSX_InstallESD/Packages /mnt/usbstick/System/Installation/
   63  rsync -aAEHW /mnt/OSX_InstallESD/BaseSystem.chunklist /mnt/usbstick/
   64  rsync -aAEHW /mnt/OSX_InstallESD/BaseSystem.dmg /mnt/usbstick/
   65  sync
```

Comment: have you tried? :) read trough the answers, try do it and then read mine :)

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trial and error, I was finally able to install OSX 10.11 "El Capitan" on my used iMac (mid 2009)!
I tried to use the internet installer that came with it, but it would not work without signing into the original owner's AppleID (even though I specifically went into iTunes to "De-Authorize this computer" before wiping the original installation)

Instead, I downloaded the "El Capitan" installer .dmg file from Apple's support page:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886

However, this contains a file called "InstallMacOSX.dmg", rather than "InstallESD.dmg". So, I needed to first convert this file into an image:
dmg2img InstallMacOSX.dmg InstallMacOSX.img
Then mount the image: In Linux Mint, I used 
right-click --> "Open With Other Application..." --> "Disk Image Mounter"
(but there are plenty of other ways to do this)
Inside, there was a large file called "InstallMacOSX.pkg", which I could extract using p7zip, or (in Linux Mint):
right-click --> "Open With Other Application" --> Archive Manager"
Inside THERE could be found the InstallESD.dmg!

However, the sha1 hash did match any of the values at:
https://github.com/notpeter/apple-installer-checksums#mac-osx-installers-sha1-checksums
6198647687 bytes, 
openssl sha1 InstallESD.dmg --> 732f873cbcf38d9e544e659d2429bd4444416cda
I am pretty sure the file is legit (since I downloaded it directly from Apple Support), so I edited the "mkosxinstallusb.sh" script and added it to the approved list
--> see the line starting with "supported_checksums="...", and just added it to the end before the last closing quote)
Also, make sure your USB thumb drive is completely empty before you start the script.  In my case, I actually plugged it into the mac and formatted it with Disk Utility to "OS X Extended (Journaled)" (GUID Partition table) before I started. (I had tried it once before with a partially occupied USB drive, and it ran out of space before it could finish).  I am not sure how much difference it made to format it with
Disk Utility, but that is what worked for me!
I then ran "sudo bash mkosxinstallusb.sh /dev/sdX "InstallESD.dmg", and the script took care of the rest.
Finally, I could boot up the Mac while holding "option/alt" and my USB drive appeared as a bootable device!  17 minutes later I can startup OSX!

I may go ahead and re-download the installer and create a new bootable USB using "createinstallmedia", just in case there was a problem with the image I used, but at least now I can boot up the computer!